# What is "bs-docs-nav" & "role" is all about?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, accessibility

I'm doing experiments on nav in bootstrap4. I'm checking codes in codepen. I studied this code but I don't understand this line `bs-docs-nav` and role attribute.

One more question what is that `role` attribute is?

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top  bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
```

Answer (score 1):

About `role="banner"`, it is an accessibility attribute via Accessible Rich Internet Applications (ARIA) which is a set of attributes that define ways to make web content and web applications (especially those developed with JavaScript) more accessible to people with disabilities.

Role banner according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Banner_role)

> A banner role represents general and informative content frequently placed at the beginning of the page. This usually includes a logo, company name, search icon, photo related to the page, or slogan

About `.bs-docs-nav`, it's a class seems it in not part standard classes of Bootstrap.
You should inspect it with browser developer tools and see what it is.

PS: Learn more about [Accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility)